# how to interpret this interaction (regression)

Tags: regression, ggplot2

So, I have model:

y = x + gender(categorical variable) + interaction(x and gender)

x and gender and interaction was all significant

and the plot y and x and gender.

[image: y and x plot]
[image: y and x plot with regression line]

[image: y and interaction]

[image: regression]
(this is simulated data without error variance so that I can clearly see what's going on).

However, the regression (OSL) says there is a significant interaction effect.

Can anyone help me with this?

how can I interpret the interaction here?

x and gender has significant interaction, but
I cannot see why ( as you can see the first two plots)

the interaction between x and gender was significant,,,

Comment: How did you obtain the first and second plot?

Comment: @frank I just plot x and y and manually put a regression line based on the regression equation that r gave me.

Comment: I think you made a mistake then. The line should be on the points.

Comment: @frank gender variable is not dummy coded but effect coded (-1, 1).

Comment: We need to know precisely how you generated the data and what is shown in the plots.